# What are the possible terms for interference in the bishop endgame?

Tags: endgame, bishop-endgame

In various positions in elementary bishop endgames, the stronger side tries to prevent the sacrifice of the bishop for the last remaining pawn by interposing the diagonal with the bishop. For example, second position in this [Centurini article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Centurini). What are the possible terms for this idea? Besides 'interference', can it be called a 'bridge', by analogy with rook endgames?

Answer (score 2):

Dvoretsky in *Endgame Manual* just calls this technique *interferring*.

*Building a bridge* in RPvR endgames is slightly different as it is about sheltering your king from checks from the enemy rook, not about preventing the rook from sacrificing itself for the last remaining pawn.